# Android Socket Programming?

Tags: java, android, sockets, client-server

I need a little bit help regarding to android socket programming. I had made a server-client prototype using java socket programming. In server client scenario , I am sending commands from 1-10 and sever do some task according to command received from client.  e.g. when server receives a command it sever will send a bufferedImage to the client. Its (java prototype) is working fine. In this scenario, both server and client a java desktop applications, Now I want to make android as a client. Can someone help me in this regard or suggest me good resources of android socket programming?

(Please note BufferedImage class is not supported by Android.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no problem in porting your application. Android runs on Java, which very similar to desktop version. All you need is to migrate `BufferedImage` to simple byte array, and to use `ImageIO` on your server side.

Comment: ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 ImageIO.write( bImage, "png", baos );
 byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
server.getOutputStream().write(data);

Comment: how I can receive byte[] at client side(android device)?

Comment: I assume that `client` is a socket on your android device. Then: `ByteInputStream stream  = new ByteInputStream(client.getInputStream()); byte[] img = stream.toByteArray();`

Comment: there is no ByteInputStream class in android, are you means ByteArrayInputStream?

Comment: What do you mean? An error? Or what? Better to accept the answer and ask another one with the code shown.

Comment: well not an error but its not working, anyways thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

@Op. Do note that you on the Android device probably also want to keep a PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK while you are downloading the image.